# Is there a name for this lyrical construct?

Tags: lyrics, taylor-swift

In Taylor Swift's song Anti-Hero, the last two lines of the chorus are:

> I'll stare directly at the sun but never in the mirror
>
> It must be exhausting always rooting for the anti-hero

But as it's sung, the It of the second line is sung within the measure of the previous line, so it's more like:

> I'll stare directly at the sun but never in the mirror (It)
>
> must be exhausting always rooting for the anti-hero

Is there a name for this division of logically separate lyrical lines?

Comment: It's not actually in the measure of the previous line. "It" is on the first beat of the next measure. You can sing along with a metronome to check. The words are just really close together. That said, I'm sure there's a word for what you're describing, I just don't know it. *Anacrusis* is similar, but specifically for the very first line/measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is enjambment, when the poetic line doesn't match the grammatical line.

https://www.poetryfoundation.org/learn/glossary-terms/enjambment

Comment: at long last.  thanks.